# How to fix missing values in id field after adding and removing primary key in django model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I added a primary key for a model but then ran into some downstream problems because the automatically generated id field was gone. Now, I removed that key again, but the id column was deleted apparently and I guess all the values are gone. So, setting a default value does not really make sense because other models need to know the old values. How can I fix that? Currently, I still get the error when I try to migrate:

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "id" of relation "pipeline_file" does not exist

Comment: sounds pretty tricky, do you have a backup of an older version of the db? you can try going through each row and re-assigning the correct IDs

Answer (score 0):

try reverting the migrations for your application:

```
python manage.py migrate --fake <your app name> zero
```

and running make migrations again. There is a nice guide here. https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/26/how-to-reset-migrations.html

unfortunately there is no way to recover the data in the lost column unless you have a backup of the database